# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named lib

Tags: python-3.x, windows, path, python-module, lib

I have cloned a GitHub repository: https://github.com/xiaojunxu/SQLNet
I have followed the steps until downloading glove embeddings. On running python extract_vocab.py I get 'no module named lib error'.

The lib file is in the folder
The directory structure is as follows:

```
SQLNet
==>sqlnet
         ==>lib
               ==>__init__
               ==>dbengine
         ==>utils.py

==>extract_vocab.py
```

On executing python extract_vocab.py it gives me the following error:

```
(sql) C:\Users\khata\SQLNet>python extract_vocab.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_vocab.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sqlnet.utils import *
  File "C:\Users\khata\SQLNet\sqlnet\utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lib.dbengine import DBEngine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

lib directory is present with dbengine in it.
I am working in WINDOWS with a python3 environment

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted the contents of the dbengine file in utils.py.Which solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change it to from .lib.dbengine import DBEngine